# how to increase height of TextView with NSTextAttachment

Tags: ios, iphone, textview

I have `UITextView` and its height increase dynamically when text increase in `UITextView`, but there are many `NSTextAttachments` (Custom Smileys) in the `UITextView` , but Height won't increase accordingly because it assumes `NSTextAttachments` as a text and `NSTextAttachments` goes out of the bounds of `UITextView`.

```
NSString *str_TextDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Content"]];

[_txtDetail setText:str_TextDetail];
[_txtDetail setNumberOfLines:0];
[_txtDetail sizeToFit];
```